# Reading Data into Solr from mysql dump

Tags: mysql, solr

i am stuck with a queer problem. i have a mysql dump file (. dmp). i want to index its contents into SOLR. the catch is, i dont want to load the dump into a running instance of my sql and then use a Data Import Handler. ( there is a limitation that the everyone in the User domain may not have mysql installed).

is there a way to do this ? has anyone copme up with a library anything to handle this task ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you dump it into any other file format like csv which can then be easily indexed by solr ?

Comment: no the .dmp file is all i get. how it is exported is out of the scope of the application and not in my control. so i'm tied down to find a work around for this.